# Maximizing variance of bounded variables

Tags: statistics, variance, maximization

Let x_1, ..., x_i,..., x_p be p real numbers such that 0 <= x_i <= b for all i.
That is, each x_i can take any value between 0 and b.
I'd like to find the values of {x_i}'s that maximize the variance among them.

Do you have any hints?
I'd like to use this result for my example code.
Or, isn't this question well-defined?

At first I thought of something like x_1=0, x_2=...=x_p=b, but then I found this does not maximize the variance when p is a little bit large.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be half of the values equal 0 and the other half equal to b?

Comment: Thank you, that sounds plausible to me. Do you have any idea on how to prove that?

Comment: Ups! My algebra is a bit rusty... (Besides, I would have to learn how to write the answer using symbols!) Just took a piece of paper, and was only able to demonstrate that, for an even `p`, the variances for values chosen like above would be (1/2)*b^2. Maybe with a numerical method... but it would be really weird! Do you really need to demonstrate it?

Comment: Well, I do not want to trouble you a lot, but it would be very helpful if you could put an outline of your process, or point me to a link that explains this. I really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comments, I did some trials on a numerical prove for your problem. There's still some work to do, but I hope it puts you in the right track. Besides, I've used `python`, and I have no idea if this is ok for you or not. You can surely find equivalent ways to do it in `matlab` and `R`.

I use the well-known property of the variance = E[X^2] - E[X]^2, to make the derivatives easier. (If you have doubts, check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition)).

The `python` package `scipy.optimize` has a method `minimize` to minimize numerically a function. You can select an algorithm for solving the problem; I'm not so familiar with the possible algorithms and I was looking for the well-known plain gradient descent (well, at least I hope you know it), and I think a closed one could be [SLSQP](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp), but honestly I'm not 100% sure on the details.

And finally, I didn't make sure that the function you're minimizing is convex, or figured out whether it has local minima, but the results look fine.

I give you the code in python below, in case it is useful, but the bottomline is that I'd suggest you:

- Choose a language/package you are familiar with
- Choose an algorithm for the optimization
- It would be nice to prove that the function is convex (so that the solution converges)
- Set the parameters for which you want to make the prove

Code below. Hope it helps.

I'm not going to post the algebra for the derivatives, I hope you can make them yourself. And you must take into account that you are maximizing and not minimizing, so you have to multiply by -1, as explained I hope quite clearly [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) (look for "maximizing").

Setup,

```
In [1]:

from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
```

The function you are maximizing, that is the variance (remember the the trick E[X^2] - E[X]^2, and the -1),

```
In [86]:

def func(x):
    return (-1) * (np.mean([xi**2 for xi in x]) - np.mean(x)**2)
```

The derivative of that function for each of the `xi` of the vector `x`, (I hope you can derivate and get to the same result),

```
In [87]:

def func_deriv(x):
    n = len(x)
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        res = (2 * x[i] / n) - ((2/(n**2)) * (x[i] + sum([x[j] for j in range(n) if j != i])))
        l +=  [(-1) * res]
    return np.array(l)
```

Actually, I made quite a few mistakes when writing this function, both in the derivative and the python implementation. But there is a trick that helps a lot, which is to check the derivative in a numeric way, by adding and subtracting a small epsilon in every dimension and calculating the slope of the curve [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation). This would the function that approximates the derivative,

```
In [72]:

def func_deriv_approx(x, epsilon=0.00001):
    l = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x_plus = [x[j]+((j == i)*epsilon) for j in range(len(x))]
        x_minus = [x[j]-((j == i)*epsilon) for j in range(len(x))]
        res = (-1) * (func(x_plus) - func(x_minus)) / (2*epsilon)
        l += [res]
    return l
```

And then I've checked `func_deriv_approx`versus `func_deriv` for a bunch of values.

And the minimizing itself. If I initialize the values to the solution we suspect is right, it works ok, it only iterates once and gives the expected results,

```
In [99]:

res = minimize(func, [0, 0, 10, 10], jac=func_deriv, bounds=[(0,10) for i in range(4)],
               method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -25.0
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 1
            Gradient evaluations: 1

In [100]:

print(res.x)
[  0.   0.  10.  10.]
```

(Note that you could use the length you wanted, since `func` and `func_deriv` are written in a way that accept any length).

You could initialize randomly like this,

```
In [81]:

import random
xinit = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(4)]

In [82]:

xinit
Out[82]:
[1, 2, 8, 7]
```

And then the maximization is,

```
In [83]:

res = minimize(func, xinit, jac=func_deriv, bounds=[(0,10) for i in range(4)],
               method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -25.0
            Iterations: 3
            Function evaluations: 3
            Gradient evaluations: 3
In [84]:

print(res.x)
[  1.27087156e-13   1.13797860e-13   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01]
```

Or finally for length = 100,

```
In [85]:

import random
xinit = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(100)]

In [91]:

res = minimize(func, xinit, jac=func_deriv, bounds=[(0,10) for i in range(100)],
               method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -24.91
            Iterations: 23
            Function evaluations: 22
            Gradient evaluations: 22
In [92]:

print(res.x)
[  2.49143492e-16   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01  -2.22962789e-16
  -3.67692105e-17   1.00000000e+01  -8.83129256e-17   1.00000000e+01
   7.41356521e-17   3.45804774e-17  -8.88402036e-17   1.31576404e-16
   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
  -3.81854094e-17   1.00000000e+01   1.25586928e-16   1.09703896e-16
  -5.13701064e-17   9.47426071e-17   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
   2.06912944e-17   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
  -5.95921560e-17   1.00000000e+01   1.94905365e-16   1.00000000e+01
  -1.17250430e-16   1.32482359e-16   4.42735651e-17   1.00000000e+01
  -2.07352528e-18   6.31602823e-17  -1.20809001e-17   1.00000000e+01
   8.82956806e-17   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   3.29717355e-16   1.00000000e+01
   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
   1.43180544e-16   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   2.31039883e-17   1.06524134e-16
   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
   1.77002357e-16   1.52683194e-16   7.31516095e-17   1.00000000e+01
   1.00000000e+01   3.07596508e-17   1.17683979e-16  -6.31665821e-17
   1.00000000e+01   2.04530928e-16   1.00276075e-16  -1.20572493e-17
  -3.84144993e-17   6.74420338e-17   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
  -9.66066818e-17   1.00000000e+01   7.47080743e-17   4.82924982e-17
   1.00000000e+01  -9.42773478e-17   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01
   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   1.00000000e+01   5.01810185e-17
  -1.75162038e-17   1.00000000e+01   6.00111991e-17   1.00000000e+01
   1.00000000e+01   7.62548028e-17  -6.90706135e-17   1.00000000e+01]
```

Comment: In case you've read my answer already; I've finally found what was wrong so I'm going to edit it massively, not respecting my original text. Please check it again in a few minutes.

Comment: This really helps, thank you very much!! Yes, I understand Python and basically replicated your idea. Thank you also for the information on derivatives. Now I think I will work on the algebra again.

Comment: Now I did! Sorry I am not very used to the system here, and thank you very much again!